# How to sort Sentinel 2A and 2B rasters based on the dates in R

Tags: raster, r, sentinel-2

I have a list of Sentinel 2A and 2B images.
I would like to sort them according to their date but R sorted them based on the names and grouped them like 2A and 2B, which can be seen below;
the code I used for this;

```
my_dirs = c("path/Data/my_mask/T18NUK")
my_fs = do.call(c, lapply(my_dirs, list.files, pattern = "*.*tif", full.names = TRUE))
my_raster <- lapply(my_fs, raster)
```

The output is;

```
SENTINEL2A_20210513-153205-267_L2A_T18NUK_C_V1-0_CLM_R1.tif
SENTINEL2A_20210516-154200-853_L2A_T18NUK_C_V1-0_CLM_R1.tif
SENTINEL2A_20210602-153206-401_L2A_T18NUK_C_V1-0_CLM_R1.tif
SENTINEL2B_20210210-154159-565_L2A_T18NUK_C_V1-0_CLM_R1.tif
SENTINEL2B_20210217-153203-301_L2A_T18NUK_C_V1-0_CLM_R1.tif
SENTINEL2B_20210220-154158-670_L2A_T18NUK_C_V1-0_CLM_R1.tif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subset the string, create a date vector, sort it and use the resulting index to order the stack.

This vector can be the result of a `list.files` call. However, note that the subsequent code is structured around the file names only and do not include a full path.

```
r <- c("SENTINEL2A_20210513-153205-267_L2A_T18NUK_C_V1-0_CLM_R1.tif",
       "SENTINEL2A_20210516-154200-853_L2A_T18NUK_C_V1-0_CLM_R1.tif",
       "SENTINEL2A_20210602-153206-401_L2A_T18NUK_C_V1-0_CLM_R1.tif",
       "SENTINEL2B_20210210-154159-565_L2A_T18NUK_C_V1-0_CLM_R1.tif",
       "SENTINEL2B_20210217-153203-301_L2A_T18NUK_C_V1-0_CLM_R1.tif",
       "SENTINEL2B_20210220-154158-670_L2A_T18NUK_C_V1-0_CLM_R1.tif")
```

Now, specific to your example we use `strsplit` and `substr` to subset the dates in the file name string. This vector is then coerced into a date class.

```
( rdate <- as.Date(unlist(lapply(strsplit(r, "_|-| + "),  
                   function(x) x[2])), "%Y%m%d") )
```

We can then sort the dates and use the `index.return` argument in `sort.int` to return the the index value that can be used to provide the correct order of file names. This index can be used directly in `stack` to reorder the file name vector.

```
( idx <- sort.int(rdate, decreasing = FALSE, index.return=TRUE) )    
  
  r[idx$ix]
  # my_raster <- stack(r[idx$ix])
```

Comment: Clear explanation and that perfectly works!